# Is there any testing tool to verify the font consistency throughout the web application?

Tags: web-applications, web, automated-tests

The purpose is to check for any inconsistency fonts used across the web application so that the developers can fix the issue.

Consistency in terms of all font properties (Font families,font sizes etc.) needs to be checked. As suggested by Pekka below, I can use CSS to define consistent font properties which can be used in all web pages but how can a QA auto test this and confirm the same CSS and hence the same font is applied to the entire web application?

Comment: Define "inconsistency of fonts". Do you mean differing font families? Couldn't they simply be sorted by fixing the CSS style sheet? Or do you mean font sizes? Those are indeed going to be tricky!

Comment: I have edited the question to answer you question

Answer (score 1):

If a font-family is set on the body tag in your stylesheet, then that font will apply to nearly every element throughout your site (form and table elements being the exception where you have to redeclare the font-family for those).

The only time the font-family declared on the body won't apply is if it's overridden by a different font-family applied on individual elements elsewhere in the stylesheet, or if it is applied by inline styles.

So you can check on font-family consistency in the stylesheet/s just be doing a search for 'font:' (for cases where shorthand is being used) and 'font-family' and making sure any references to it match what your default font should be.

To override different fonts set by inline style, take a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/).